# Operator precedence in typescript shorthand array notation: typeof unknown[]

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, operator-precedence, type-declaration

In puppeteer's declaration file types.d.ts, I came across the following type definition:

```
  export declare type EvaluateFunc<T extends unknown[]>
      = (...params: InnerParams<T>) => Awaitable<unknown>;


  export declare type InnerParams<T extends unknown[]> = {
      [K in keyof T]: FlattenHandle<T[K]>;
  };
```

My question is in regards to **<T extends unknown[]>** and the operator precedence for `typeof` and `[]` .. is T extending unknown? Or is it extending `unknown[]`, and, if it's the latter, then is the keyof operator able to be used on type `Array`? If so, does typescript take this to mean 'any numeric property of an array'? (aka, array item).

Assuming it's the former, and T is extending unknown, then how does the array shorthand `[]` operator affect the `typeof` operator? Just for context, here is the definition for `FlattenHandle`:

```
export declare type FlattenHandle<T> = T extends HandleOr<infer U> ? U : never;
```

Sub-question: `export declare` -- I've taken a break from TS for half a year and now that I'm back, I'm seeing these more and more. Is it a recent addition? What are we trying to say here? That, the type exists but was not exported in the source? One of the affects of this `export declare` is that my IDE (PHPStorm) thinks that the class ElementHandle exists, and even appears in console.log, but, if you `Console.log(ElementHandle)` you will get `undefined`:

```
export declare class ElementHandle<ElementType extends Node = Element> extends JSHandle<ElementType> {
    #private;
    // ...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `T` is constrained to extend `unknown[]`. If you use the `keyof` operator on a tuple in a mapped type, you can map over each element thanks to [mapped tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25947). `K` will in this case be an index number.

Comment: Where is the `typeof` operator here? I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: "*Sub-question*" - that's totally unrelated. Please [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that.

Comment: The `typeof` operator? Do you you mean the `extends` operator?

Comment: You seem to assume the operator precedence of `T extends unknown[]` is `(T extends unknown)[]`. But that doesn't make sense, this is the declaration of generic parameters, with their names and optionally constraints. You cannot have array syntax in there: something like `type EvaluateFunc<T[]>` is just a syntax error.

Comment: @TobiasS. Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for Can you add it as the answer?. jcalz, yes, you are right, I meant 'keyof' -- I was mentally exhausted when I wrote the post. I meant to say: what is the type of 'keyof unknown[]'. Bergi will do! It works sometimes :P And yes, I meant extends/ 'keyof unknown[]'